# More general definition of expected value

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable with pdf $f$. I would like to know why:

$$\operatorname{E} [X]  = \int_\Omega X \, \mathrm{d}P = \int_\Omega X(\omega) P(\mathrm{d}\omega)= \int_{-\infty}^\infty x f(x)\, \mathrm{d}x .   $$

I mean I don't get it why it is all equal and what the notation in third term means. Thanks for any calrification.

Comment: I think if you let your probability measure be the (absolutely continuous) CDF, you end up with the fourth term. (This is based on my very naive understanding of probability theory.)

Comment: "All equal"? Well, 2 and 3 are equivalent and *define* 1 while 4 is a theorem which follows from the definition of the distribution of X. What do you want in surplus of [the obvious](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value)?

Comment: "while 4 is a theorem which follows from the definition of the distribution of X"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us show that
$$
\int_\Omega g(X)\,\mathrm dP=\int_\mathbb{R}g\, \mathrm d P_X=\int_\mathbb{R} gf\mathrm d\lambda,\tag{1}
$$
for all measurable $g$ such that $g(X)$ is integrable. Here $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue-measure.

To this end, let $g$ be an indicator function, i.e. $g=\mathbf{1}_B$ for some Borel set $B\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. Then
$$
\int_\Omega g(X)\,\mathrm dP=\int_\Omega \mathbf{1}_{X^{-1}(B)}\,\mathrm dP=P_X(B)=\int_\mathbb{R} g\,\mathrm dP_X.
$$
Thus, the first equality of $(1)$ holds for indicator functions and can easily be extended to a general $g$ by using the linearity of the integral.

As for the second equality we have, with the same $g$, that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}g\,\mathrm dP_X=P_X(B)=\int_B f\,\mathrm d\lambda=\int_\mathbb{R} gf\,\mathrm d\lambda,
$$
since $X$ has density $f$ with respect to $\lambda$. Thus, the second equality of $(1)$ holds for indicator functions and can easily be extended to a general $g$.

To answer your question, let $g$ be the identity function, i.e. $g(x)=x$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X$ be a random variable in the probability space $(\mathsf \Omega, \mathsf \Sigma, \mathsf P)$; where $\mathsf \Omega$ is the sample space, $\mathsf \Sigma$ is the set of events (each event containing zero or more outcomes), and $\mathsf P$ be the probability measure.

Then by definition the expected value is the integration of all possible values of the random variable over the sample space with respect to the probability measure.

$$\mathsf E [X]  = \int_\mathsf \Omega X \, \operatorname{d}\mathsf P$$

More generally, if $X$ can be expressed as a measurable function of individual outcomes $\omega$ within the sample space then:

$$\mathsf E [X]  = \int_\mathsf\Omega X(\omega) \, \operatorname{d}\mathsf P(\omega) = \int_\mathsf\Omega X(\omega) \, \mathsf P(\operatorname{d}\omega)$$

(You might be more familiar with the middle notation; they equivalently mean that the integration is with respect to the measure of the outcome and over the sample space $\mathsf\Omega$. The later notation just more correctly identifies that we're integrating over the domain of the outcomes, rather than the domain of the probability measure.)

In the specific case where we have let $X$ be a random variable with pdf $f$, then the probability space is implicitly the real domain $\mathsf \Omega\equiv (-\infty,\infty)$, the individual outcomes ($\omega$) may be represented as a real variable ($x$), the value of the random variable at each outcome is simply the outcome, $X(x)=x$, and by the definition of the probability density: $f(x)\mathrm d x \equiv \mathsf P(\operatorname{d}x)$, so :

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf E[X] & = \int_\mathsf\Omega X\operatorname{d}\mathsf P
\\ & = \int_\mathsf\Omega X(\omega)\mathsf P(\operatorname{d}\omega) & \because X, \mathsf P \text{ are measurable functions of }\omega\in\mathsf\Omega 
\\ & = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} X(\omega) \mathsf P(\operatorname{d}\omega) & \because \text{here } \mathsf\Omega = \mathbb R
\\ & = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} X(x) \mathsf P(\operatorname{d}x) & \because \text{change of variable, } \omega = x
\\ & = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x \; \mathsf P(\operatorname{d}x) & \because \text{here } X(x)=x
\\ & = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x \; f(x)\operatorname{d} x & \because f(x) \mathop{:\!}=\frac{\operatorname{d}\mathsf P(x)}{\operatorname{d} x}
\end{align}$$

Comment: The three integrals in the beginning of your post are not defined differently (which it seems that you implying), they are just notational varieties for the same object. Also a random variable is by definition a measurable function, and hence I do not understand the sentence "More generally, if $X$ can be expressed as a measurable function..."

Comment: Also, when a random variable $X$ admits a density, the underlying probability space on which $X$ is defined need _not_ be $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: "In the specific case where we have let X be a random variable with pdf f, then the probability space is implicitly the real domain Ω≡(−∞,∞)" Sorry but this quite untrue, actually forcing the probability space to be the real domain ℝ causes quite a few problems as soon as one must deal with more than one random variable. It seems you are confusing the source set Ω and the target set ℝ.

Comment: I got a question - what definition of density function is it? $f(x)\mathrm d x \equiv \mathsf P(\operatorname{d}x)$ I've never seen it before and I thought I knew what it was.