# Confusion over joint probability and joint expectation

Tags: probability, notation

This question is likely mainly a notational issue, but I would greatly appreciate some clarification.

Consider two (discrete) random variables X and Y. It makes sense to think about the joint probability distribution between the two rv’s, which can be written as $f(x,y)=P(X=x,Y=y)$. Note the commas. Does it make sense to also think about a joint expectation, denoted as $E(X,Y)$? Is there a requirement that the expectation operator only takes one “argument”? Why?

I often see $E(XY)$ but I don’t think this is the same thing, as this is the expectation of a new random variable $Z=XY$ which the product of X and Y.

Comment: If $\mu_X = E(X),\; \mu_Y= E(Y),$ you might say the 'center' of the joint distribution is $(\mu_X,\mu_Y).$ Also, as you say, $E(XY)$ would be the mean of the r.v $XY,$ but I have no idea what $E(X,Y)$ might refer to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability is a value attributed to an *event* which is a subset of a *sample space*, $\Omega$, e.g, $P\{A\}$ is the probability of the occurrence of $A\subseteq \Omega$. A joint probability, something like $P\{A,B\}$, is the probability of the *intersection* of $A$ and $B$, i.e., the probability of both $A$ and $B$ occur. Using such a notation, the *comma* constitutes the logical binary operation: *and*.

A random variable usually attributes a *quantity* to an *outcome* or an *event*. It is actually a function as $X(\omega): \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, or other plausible numeric domains. The *expectation* operation returns the quantity that we expect (on average) for that random variable to be, according to the probability distribution of the random variable, or equivalently, the probability distribution of the events. Using such a notation, $E\{X\}$ is actually $E\{X(\omega)\}$ over all $\omega\in\Omega$. So, the expectation is an operation on a random variable with a numerical support. In that case, $E\{X,Y\}$ is not quite meaningful.

As unusual as it is, if $X(\omega)$ represents a set (a subset of some other universal set), as well as some $Y(\omega)$, then by the above-mentioned conventions, $E\{X,Y\}$ could be interpreted as the expectation of the *intersection* of $X$ and $Y$. The result in that case should be a *set*.

Comment: I made corrections.

Answer (score 1):

I think the confusion is due to the fact that joint probability density functions do not have expected values, but instead, random variable have expected values.

Informally, the expected value is an operator that takes a random variable as input and returns the most likely value of the random variable. Thus, the notation $\text{E}[X,Y]$ is not valid and doesn't make much sense. However, the notation $\text{E}[XY]$ is valid and is equivalent to $\text{E}[Z]$ where $Z = XY$. This is valid because $Z$ is a random variable. You might be interested in the [law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician), which is related to computing the expectation of a function of random variables.

Formally, the expected value of a random variable $X$ with probability density function $f(x)$ is given by

$$ \text{E}[X] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} x f(x) dx $$

You can find a more general definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#General_case) with further explanation in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/919047/372907), but given the question, I don't think the general definition is necessary.